# Error in calling a class in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am unable to use a example from there 
I am testing out the sample here

http://cloud.verizon.com/documentation/AuthenticationRESTCallExample.htm

I am calling them by using (This is for sample)

```
secretKey="xxxxxxxxx"
accessKey="Xxxxxxxxx"
restVerb="GET"
apiResource="'https://api.cloud.verizon.com/api/cloud/vdisk-template/"
VzREST(secretKey,accessKey).request(restVerb,apiResource)
```

But I am getting a error like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\admins\a1.py", line 176, in <module>
VzREST(secretKey,accessKey).request(restVerb,apiResource)
File "C:\Python34\admins\a1.py", line 171, in request
restVerb,apiResource=apiResource),data=data)
File "C:\Python34\admins\a1.py", line 103, in _reqREST
apiResource = self._stripAndEncodeApiResource(apiResource)
File "C:\Python34\admins\a1.py", line 45, in _stripAndEncodeApiResource
return re.sub(self._url, '', apiResource.encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
File "C:\Python34\lib\re.py", line 175, in sub
return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

What's the error I am making here? Whether I am calling it wrongly (I am not so good in Python)

Comment: I assume the code snippet you're using is for Python 2.x, not for Python 3.x. As as side note, it's (as often) a rather unpythonic code...

Comment: you have a stray `'` in your url also

Comment: Why is apiResource encoded on line 45? I suspect that leads to the error.

Comment: I think your example code is compatible with python2 and not python3. You are trying to run it in python3. AFAIK there is no encode methods with string types in python3 as they are unicodes. Or you may need to change the sample code to be compatible with python3

Comment: are you sure the library is compatible with python3 ? the sample is python 2 only. (you can see as it is using the print statement without braces). It won't work with python3

Comment: Thanks all..it seems the above code will work only with Python 2.7